# missing import statements after downloading google-java-api-client

Tags: importerror, google-api-java-client, youtube-data-api

I plan on using the Youtube Data API 3 with Java and Eclipse as my IDE.

- I have installed the google-api-java-client (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/#Downloads).
- I add all the .jar files from the google-api-java-client/libs folder to my project's build path. I do this by right clicking my project, build path, configure build path, libraries tab, Add external jars, and select all from google-api-java-client/libs.
- I paste a sample example -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#examples

My result is that I have errors with most of my import statements. 
The only error free import statements are :

- import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
- import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;

I get errors when I have import statements with :

- import com.google.api.services
- import com.google.common

It seems that I only have files related to com.google.api.client and not com.google.api.services or com.google.common.

Have I made a mistake in building my path? Can anyone guide me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get com.google.api.services by downloading the .jar file from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube/v3-rev107-1.18.0-rc ...